# Exception in custom validator in Grails

Tags: hibernate, validation, grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I'm trying to implement password validation in Grais on a `User` domain entity created via spring security core plugin. I have added the following code in my entity:

```
class User {
  // Added by the spring security core plugin
  String password
  // Added by me
  String passwordConfirm

  static constraints = {
    passwordConfirm blank:false, validator: { val, obj ->
       if (!obj.password.equals(obj.passwordConfirm)) {
           return "user.password.confirmation.error"
       }
    }
  }

  // other methods...
}
```

The validator works as expected when `password` doesn't match `passwordConfirm`. However, when the validator passes successfully and the instance is about to be persisted, i get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.test.User entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

    at com.shopify.RegistrationController$_closure2.doCall(RegistrationController.groovy:14)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I am persisting my entity using `user.save(flush: true)`.

When i remove the validation, my instance is successfully persisted in the database, therefore i assume that there must be something wrong with my validator. Do you have any suggestions on what might be wrong? I am using grails version 2.0.4.

EDIT: The part where i save my entity has as follows:

```
def register = {    
    def user = new User(params)
    if (!user.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)) {
        render view: 'register', model: [userInstance: user]
    } else {
        render view: 'success'
    }
}
```

EDIT: Okay, i managed to make this work by commenting out the following code that was inserted by spring security core:

```
def beforeInsert() {
    // encodePassword()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    // if (isDirty('password')) {
    //  encodePassword()
    // }
}
```

At the moment, i have no idea why this happens but i'll check this out. In the mean time if anyone has any info on this, i would really be interested in sharing it with me.

EDIT: Found this related bug report: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9083

Comment: Can you add this to the save to get a more detailed error log user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

Comment: Can you post the whole part of the code that is saving the obj ? instead of just the user.save()

Comment: Your validator should compare `obj.password` against `val` (the value being validated) rather than `obj.passwordConfirm`.

Comment: I did try that but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The validation fails because before your User is inserted, it hashes your password, therefore password no longer equals the passwordConfirm, triggering the validation error.

here's what you are doing:

before save():

```
def password = 1234
def passwordConfirm = 1234
password == passwordConfirm  validation passes
```

during .save(). before insert is triggered:

```
def password gets hashed:  
def password = 1JO@J$O!@J$P!O@$JP!@O$J!@O$J!@
def passwordConfirm = 1234
password != passwordConfirm validation fails
```

after removing encodePassword() from your domain:

```
def password = 1234
def passwordConfirm = 1234
password == passwordConfirm  validation passes but now you have your password in plain texts inside your DB, you should never do this for security reasons.
```

Easy fix would be doing the validation in a separate command object, not within the domain object it self, the passwordConfirm shouldn't even be in your domain class.

Example:
Take a look at Spring Security UI's [source](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugins/springsecurity/ui/RegisterController.groovy), see how it handles the validation in controller with a command object.

Comment: I don't get a validation error, i get an Exception. Not sure if this is the case.

Comment: If you read the comment section of that JIRA ticket that you linked, you'll notice it was also caused by a failed validation, and the reason why the error wasn't displayed.